# How to charge RecurringApplicationCharge for Partner-Friendly apps?

Tags: shopify

Shopify says that in order to qualify for Partner-Friendly apps, we need to "not charge" for development stores. Here is the link (TIP section): https://help.shopify.com/en/api/app-store/charging-for-your-app

It says we should grant free access if  *{ "plan_name" : "affiliate" })*

When we set the price 0 on RecurringApplicationCharge, we get an error. How do we grant free access ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the **test** attribute to be true. That way no charge is levied for that install. Just add **test: true** if partner is affiliate.

One thing to monitor is the change in plan. If an affiliate plan goes real, remove the old test charge and replace it with a non-test charge subscription.

It remains painful for that reason, to deal in the freebies like this.

Comment: How do I create a RecurringApplicationCharge without user interaction? I thought I needed a user-approval cycle (ie. with a callback and everything). Can I just create a RecurringApplicationCharge and make it be accepted offline?

Comment: You create a charge with code and since it is only possible with a session token from a shop, ie: for a shop, Shopify will ask the merchant the next time they authenticate, to accept the charge or not. So you make it, the merchant decides what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Don't add a charge at all. Just activate the account like you would if a charge is successful. Afterwards, when the plan changes, set a redirect to the charge token URL.

You should have a flag on your user's data-object that lets you know if their plan is active/pending, etc.